# AngularJS: Using list item as variable for separate list

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, variables, scope

So in my controller I have these arrays with object items in them:

```
$scope.johnny = [
    {quote: "Anything for My Princess", path: 'sounds/AnythingForMyPrincess.mp3'},
    {quote: "Don't Even Ask", path: 'sounds/DontEventAsk.mp3'},
    {quote: "Don't Plan Too Much", path: 'sounds/DontPlanTooMuch.mp3'}
] //there are many more lists like this one
```

and I would like to go through these lists by using another array (names of array) and a for loop:

```
$scope.totalNames = [$scope.johnny, $scope.lisa, $scope.mark, $scope.denny, $scope.lisasmom, 
                    $scope.chicken, $scope.chris, $scope.flower, $scope.mike, $scope.steven]

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalNames.length; i++) {
    var list = $scope.totalNames[i];
    alert(list.quote);
}
```

$scope.totalNames[i] returns the correct array; however once I add the .quote to it the it returns undefined. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$scope.totalNames` is a list of list. You should so this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.totalNames.length; i++) {
    var list = $scope.totalNames[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
        alert(list[j].quote);
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, didn't see that one. Thanks a lot.